# (change) on select not calling function angular 5

Tags: angular, onchange

I have a select in a form:

```
<form #selectform="ngForm">
        <select
          id="cityselect"
          class="mt-3 text-white"
          autofocus
          (change)="browse()"
          name="cityselect"
          ngModel>
          <option value="" selected>Select Your City</option>
          <option *ngFor="let city of cities"
                  [value]="city.city">{{city.city}}</option>
        </select>
      </form>
```

and the typescript file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild,OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
 @ViewChild('selectform') selectform: NgForm;
  browse(){
    console.log('it worked');
    const city = this.selectform.form.value.cityselect;
    this.router.navigate(['/browse', city]);

  }
```

the browse function is not being called when I select a value of which I currently have two. Not sure What I may be doing wrong. I have no errors in my console that might block the event.

Comment: Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaxrvx). I copied your code, and I see "it worked" in the console when I select an item in the list.

Comment: ok thank you. That means something is holding this thing up. Ill figure out what.